# Dummies conditional on dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a dataframe with a bunch of names

```
df['NAME']=['Zamboni, Clemente', 'Strada, Gino', 'Zeldina, Laura', 'Silvestri, Simone']
```

a dictionary with the same names as keys, and with list values

```
mydict={'Zamboni, Clemente' : [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110], 
'Strada, Gino' : [103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114], 
'Zeldina, Laura' : [111, 112, 113], 
'Silvestri, Simone' : [113]}
```

and a list containing all unique numbers appearing in the dictionary:

```
mylist = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114]
```

I want to create a dummy variable for each element in mylist, which is equal to one if the element is in the value of the dictionary associated with the name: so for 'Silvestri, Simone' all dummies should take value 0 except for '113'.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
for k in df['NAME']:
    if k in mydict:
        for c in mylist:
            if c in mydict[k]:
                df[c][k] = 1
            else:
                df[k,c] = 0
```

Any hint would be much appreciated!

Comment: `dictionary = {key: {num: int(num in mydict[key]) for num in mylist} for key in mykeys}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think unutbu's answer is quite elegant, but seems to fail recognizing 113 is shared by 'Strada, Gino', 'Zeldina, Laura', 'Silvestri, Simone'. You can fix it this way.

For your question, the key point is that your `dict` implies `'Zeldina, Laura'  'Zamboni, Clemente'  'Silvestri, Simone'  'Strada, Gino'` are observations whereas `[100 - 114]` are observed values. What you want to do is actually the other way around. You want to set `[100 - 114]` as observation labels whereas `'Zeldina, Laura'  'Zamboni, Clemente'  'Silvestri, Simone'  'Strada, Gino'` are their 4 possible values. So some manual processing to convert the format is inevitable.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mydict={'Zamboni, Clemente' : [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110], 
'Strada, Gino' : [103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114], 
'Zeldina, Laura' : [111, 112, 113], 
'Silvestri, Simone' : [113]}

mylist = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114]

temp = []
for _, value in mydict.items():
    temp.append(pd.Series(value, index=value).reindex(mylist))

df = pd.concat(temp, axis=1)
df.columns = list(mydict.keys())

df.apply(lambda col: np.where(col.isnull(), 0, 1))


Out[40]: 
     Zeldina, Laura  Zamboni, Clemente  Silvestri, Simone  Strada, Gino
100               0                  1                  0             0
101               0                  1                  0             0
102               0                  1                  0             0
103               0                  1                  0             1
104               0                  1                  0             1
105               0                  1                  0             1
106               0                  1                  0             1
107               0                  1                  0             1
108               0                  1                  0             1
109               0                  1                  0             1
110               0                  1                  0             1
111               1                  0                  0             1
112               1                  0                  0             1
113               1                  0                  1             1
114               0                  0                  0             1
```

Comment: I was only able to test this now, and it does solve my problem (I just need to transpose the data frame at the end). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `df.pivot`:

```
import pandas as pd
mydict={
    'Zamboni, Clemente' : [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110], 
    'Strada, Gino' : [103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114], 
    'Zeldina, Laura' : [111, 112, 113], 
    'Silvestri, Simone' : [113]}

df = pd.DataFrame(((val,key) for key, values in mydict.items() for val in values),
                  columns=['index','name'])
df['val'] = 1
print(df.pivot(index='index', columns='name', values='val').fillna(0))
```

yields

```
name   Silvestri, Simone  Strada, Gino  Zamboni, Clemente  Zeldina, Laura
index                                                                    
100                    0             0                  1               0
101                    0             0                  1               0
102                    0             0                  1               0
103                    0             1                  1               0
104                    0             1                  1               0
105                    0             1                  1               0
106                    0             1                  1               0
107                    0             1                  1               0
108                    0             1                  1               0
109                    0             1                  1               0
110                    0             1                  1               0
111                    0             1                  0               1
112                    0             1                  0               1
113                    1             1                  0               1
114                    0             1                  0               0
```